# Swift animation chaining using CGAffineTransforms

Tags: swift, animation, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to create a background animation for my app. What I'm trying to achieve for part of it is:

1) An image (random colour / shape chosen from an array) appears randomly on the view. 2) It then grows in size rapidly (from not visible, to visible). 3) Then will slowly move in a given direction, while rotating, for 10ish seconds. 4) Then it will scale back down to a non-visible size and be removed from the view.

What I'm finding is that the shape will appear correctly in steps 1 and 2. Then, the shape will jump to a random position on the screen at the start of animation/step 3 (transition3 in the below code). While it moves, it also decreases in size. Then for step 4 it jumps back to it's original position in step 1 & 2, before shrinking off the screen as intended.

I cannot for the life of me work out what's going on here. I'm hoping I haven't missed something embarrassingly obvious.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
class BackgroundAnimation {

func animation(animationView: UIView) {

    let colourArray = [
    UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.80, blue:0.05, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.06, green:0.22, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.18, blue:0.30, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.35, green:0.77, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.61, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0)
    ]

    let imageArray = [
    "Cross",
    "Circle",
    "Halfmoon",
    "Square",
    "Triangle"
    ]

    //Animation constants
    let initialDimensions = 10
    let pathLength: CGFloat = 100
    let pathDuration = 10
    let scaleFactor: CGFloat = 5
    let scaleDuration = 1

    //Select the random image and random colour that is to be animated.
    let image = UIImage(named: imageArray[Int.random(in: 0...imageArray.count - 1)])
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)


    imageView.image = imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.tintColor = colourArray[Int.random(in: 0...colourArray.count - 1)]
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: initialDimensions, height: initialDimensions)
    animationView.insertSubview(imageView, at: 0)

    //create a random start location and angle of direction
    let startPointX = CGFloat.random(in: 0...animationView.frame.width)
    let startPointY = CGFloat.random(in: 0...animationView.frame.height)
    let pathAngle = CGFloat.random(in: 0...(CGFloat.pi * 2))
    imageView.center = CGPoint(x: startPointX, y: startPointY)

    //Calculate the endpoint from path angle and length
    let translationX = pathLength * sin(pathAngle)
    let tanslationY = -(pathLength * cos(pathAngle))


    //Define the transitions for the aniamtion
    var transition1 = CGAffineTransform.identity
    transition1 = transition1.scaledBy(x: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor)


    var transition2 = CGAffineTransform.identity
    transition2 = transition2.translatedBy(x: translationX, y: tanslationY)
    transition2 = transition2.rotated(by: CGFloat.random(in: CGFloat.pi * 1/4 ... CGFloat.pi * 3/4))


    var transition3 = CGAffineTransform.identity
    transition3 = transition3.scaledBy(x: 0.001, y: 0.001)




    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(scaleDuration), delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {

        imageView.transform = transition1

    }, completion: {finished in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(pathDuration), delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {

            imageView.transform = transition2

        }, completion: { finished in

            UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(scaleDuration), delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {

                imageView.transform = transition3

            }, completion: { finished in

                imageView.removeFromSuperview()

            })

        })

    })

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

change your position with imageView.center OR imageView.frame.origin

```
imageView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: translationX, y: tanslationY)
```

but you should calculate the destination, then set frame.origin to the destination

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me! I've implemented the change and now the movement works when I calculate the endPointx and endPointY. However, when I try to apply the rotation with:  `var transition2 = CGAffineTransform.identity
transition2 = transition2.rotated(by: CGFloat.random(in: CGFloat.pi * 1/4 ... CGFloat.pi * 3/4))`  `imageView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: endPointX, y: endPointY)
imageView.transform = transition2`  the object rotates, but also gets smaller as it moves to its destination. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Too long for a comment, I will show the code in another answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ref to Ehsan's helpful response:

This has fixed the movement issue, but the imageView is getting smaller when I try to apply the rotation in the second animation block. Updated code below:

```
class BackgroundAnimation {

func animation(animationView: UIView) {

    let colourArray = [
    UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.80, blue:0.05, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.06, green:0.22, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.18, blue:0.30, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.35, green:0.77, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.61, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0)
    ]

    let imageArray = [
    "Cross",
    "Circle",
    "Halfmoon",
    "Square",
    "Triangle"
    ]

    //Animation constants
    let initialDimensions = 10
    let pathLength: CGFloat = 100
    let pathDuration = 10
    let scaleFactor: CGFloat = 3
    let scaleDuration = 1

    //Select the random image and random colour that is to be animated.
    let image = UIImage(named: imageArray[Int.random(in: 0...imageArray.count - 1)])
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)


    imageView.image = imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.tintColor = colourArray[Int.random(in: 0...colourArray.count - 1)]
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: initialDimensions, height: initialDimensions)
    animationView.insertSubview(imageView, at: 0)

    //create a random start location and angle of direction
    let startPointX = CGFloat.random(in: 0...animationView.frame.width * 0.9)
    let startPointY = CGFloat.random(in: 0...animationView.frame.height * 0.9)
    let pathAngle = CGFloat.random(in: 0...(CGFloat.pi * 2))
    imageView.center = CGPoint(x: startPointX, y: startPointY)

    //Calculate the endpoint from path angle and length
    let translationX = pathLength * sin(pathAngle)
    let translationY = (pathLength * cos(pathAngle))

    let endPointX = startPointX + translationX
    let endPointY = startPointY + translationY

    //Define the transitions for the aniamtion
    var transition1 = CGAffineTransform.identity
    transition1 = transition1.scaledBy(x: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor)


    var transition2 = CGAffineTransform.identity
    transition2 = transition2.rotated(by: CGFloat.random(in: CGFloat.pi * 1/4 ... CGFloat.pi * 3/4))



    var transition3 = CGAffineTransform.identity
    transition3 = transition3.scaledBy(x: 0.001, y: 0.001)




    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(scaleDuration), delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {

        imageView.transform = transition1

    }, completion: {finished in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(pathDuration), delay: 0.5, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .curveLinear], animations: {

            imageView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: endPointX, y: endPointY)
            imageView.transform = transition2

        }, completion: { finished in

            UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(scaleDuration), delay: 0.5, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {

                imageView.transform = transition3

            }, completion: { finished in

                imageView.removeFromSuperview()

            })

        })

    })

}
```

}